# Copy and bit-invert ints in an std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, bitwise

I want a second copy of an `std::vector` in which all elements are inverted, e.g. `0x01` in the first vector should be `0xFE` in the second.

Is this a good solution?

```
std::vector<uint8_t> first_list = {0x01, 0x10, 0x32, 0x1A };
std::vector<uint8_t> second_list = first_list;
for(std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator it = second_list.begin(); it != second_list.end(); ++it)
    *it = ~*it;
```

The for loop sticks out to me as unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new `for()` in C++11

```
std::vector<uint8_t> first_list = {0x01, 0x10, 0x32, 0x1A};
std::vector<uint8_t> second; 
for(uint8_t& it: first_list)
{   second.push_back(~it);
}
```

Comment: This kind of `for` loop is what I've been wishing for every time I've written one with an explicitly incrementing iterator!

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize `std::transform` here (I'll assume C++11 for the lambda):

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> first_list = {0x01, 0x10, 0x32, 0x1A};
    std::vector<uint8_t> second; 
    std::transform(first_list.begin(), first_list.end(), std::back_inserter(second),
                   [](uint8_t u) { return ~u; });
}
```

You also don't need to make a copy of the first vector to do this; better to simply use `push_back` (or `back_inserter` here, since we're working with iterators).

Comment: Frankly, written out as a for loop is kind of less code than using `transform` with a lambda.